# jQuery slideToggle adding mysterious margin to parent <li>

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I've got a `<ul>` with 5 `<li>` items. Each list item has a headline and a paragraph. I'm using `slideToggle()` to display the paragraph when you click the headline.

But, when you click the headline a second time the `slideToggle()` hides the paragraph but adds some white space to the `<li>`. The more I click the headline to toggle the paragraph, the more white space appears.

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#content ul li h3').click(function(){
            $(this).next('p').slideToggle('fast');
        }) 
    });
```

My CSS:

```
#content ul li p {
            display:none;
        }
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="content"> 
  <ul class="faq">
        <li>
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Paragraph Text<br>More text...</p>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it:  http://jsfiddle.net/dKqkZ/

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3mMZ/1/) of your code.  I do not see the problem you describe. (in Safari.)

Comment: Blasted! in my global css file I had `display:inline;` set for the `li`. That was the problem! I don't know why I didn't look there. I must have added that for some teasing I was doing. Sorry for the wasted time.

Comment: @Ofeargall, only two options now...  Post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer (best),  or just delete this whole thing (okay).  Just leaving this question hanging "as-is" is the least favorable thing.

Comment: @Sparky672, Good word! Thanks for catching me on this. The answer, lame as it is, follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the trouble..

In my Global style sheet I had `.faq li { display:inline; }`

Once I removed this everything worked exactly as it should.